# How to fix Unresolved Reference Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an error message that states: "Procedure `[schemaName].[my_proc]` has an unresolved reference to object `[dbo].[callingProc]`. I searched the web, but there doesn't appear to be many solutions. Do you have any suggestions? My Code looks something like the following:

```
create procedure schemaName.[my_proc]
as
    begin
        declare @variable int 0;

        exec dbo.callingProc
            @variable;
    end;
```

Comment: so do you have a `callingProc` proc in your db?

Comment: This is a simplified version with names that help describe what it is! But yes, `dbo.callingProc` represents a proc in my database.

Comment: so is there a `whateverIt'sReallyCalled` proc in your db, then?

Comment: Is the error happening on the `create procedure shemaName.[my_proc]` or is it happening when you try to invoke procedure `[shemaName].[my_proc]` ?

Comment: It occurs on the `dbo.callingProc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little more research and found the solution!

The `dbo.callingProc` and `schemaName.[my_proc]` were under different schema names. I went into the Database and changed the `dbo.callingProc` "Build Action" to "Build." The `dbo.callingProc` was not getting compiled, so it produced the reference error because the procedure could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

What message is trying to tell you is that there is no `[dbo].[callingProc]` procedure in your database.

Reason for this might be as simple as typo, or `callingProc` might be under different schema than `dbo`.

Comment: I believe that they are under different schema names since `callingProc` is `dbo.callingProc` and `my_proc` is `schemaName.my_proc`. Is there any easy fix for something like this?

Comment: Could you try running `exec dbo.callingProc 0;` and let me know the result.

Comment: I am not sure if I want to run this... Not sure if it will damage any of the data in the database.